# How to identify if the word in the sentence is used as adjective or verb?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning

Is there any logic/ Trick to identify if the word was used as adjective or verb?

e.g.

> Level has been reduced to one. 
>   My pen has been broken.
>   Gold had been stolen.

In above sentence the word reduced, Broken, Stolen, can be use and *verb* if we use agent.

e.g

> Level has been reduced by administrator.
> My pen has been broken by my friend.
>   Gold had been stolen by thief.

Also if I use time expression like *since* then the word reduced, Broken, stolen would be use as adjective.

e.g.

> Level has been reduced since last year.
> Since yesterday my pen has been broken.
>   Gold had been stolen but police are clueless.

Comment: The agent is *implicit* in the passive forms lacking a "by-phrase".  "The stolen gold lay on the table."  There, *stolen* is an adjective.

Comment: There are various tricks, e.g you can normally use "very" before an adjective but not before a verb (*The jacket was very moth-eaten* but not *The sandwich was very eaten*), but no rule applies in all cases, so you have to use your judgment.

Answer (score 0):

Either you have clear indications for a passive as by + passive agent or you have to decide by logic whether the structure describes a passive action or a state. In some cases both views can be right.